# Javascript: best practical way to declare functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

The past few sites I worked on and primarily event driven using jquery and i usually make my functions as so

```
function abc() {
    //do stuff
}
abc();
```

and

```
function foo() {
    var a = $('.aaa');
    var b = $('.bbb');
    var c = $('.ccc');

    function animal() {
        //do stuff
    }
    animal();

    function pet() {
        //do stuff
    }
    pet();
}
foo();
```

I know its not the best practice but, im still learning and it seems to work. I just would like to know the way I should handle this for now on.

Comment: This is so... wrong. I'm sorry but _What is your question_ and what do you expect to get from this line `var = cat, dog, mouse`? except for an error. Also: event driven? there is nothing here to even suggest that you're dealing with events

Comment: why do you have functions in functions? surely if you can declare a function in one function, surely the statements can just go in one function? And where are your ';'s ? javascript just throws errors without them.

Comment: @ChristopherKenney Closures and ASI.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem just asking the best practices for declaring functions. i fixed the rest to give a better example?

Comment: @ChristopherKenney closures, i just found out a better way to make them although would still like to know the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the code in your example (the first one) is not the best thing you can do if you're defining all these functions in the global scope (like properties/methods of the global object window). I prefer using module pattern http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript
I recommend you to read the whole book in the upper link. Another thing which is extremely useful - Stoyan Stefanov's JS Patterns book [http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Patterns-Stoyan-Stefanov/dp/0596806752](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752).

Another alternative of your example (the second one) is self-executing function:

```
(function () {
   //attaching events and doing all other stuff
}());
```

Self-executing functions are helping you to do some initialization work when loading the page for first time. You can attach events or/and do another stuff which you should do once. It's preventing you from polluting the global scope and doing init multiple times.

Comment: does using this instead of the way I did it have any advantages or disadvantages?

i took a look at the book from addy and most of the patterns went over my head and seemed like overkill for the work I need done. Is it one pattern I should spend some time with over the others?

Comment: Assuming the function isn't executed more than once in the scope, your IIFE is more appropriate indeed. Otherwise, I don't see anything wrong with declaring a function if it's inside another function as it'll be scoped anyway.

Comment: @delboud: of course this has advantages: a scope, created by an anonymous function cannot be created again: the closure is absolute. In your example there is nothing preventing me to do `foo(); foo();`

Comment: Yes, that's right. Using self-executing functions is useful for attaching events and doing initialization work on the first page load (just once).

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem is right. The main advantage is executing the function just once and preventing from polluting the global scope.

Comment: Is it ok to have multiple anonymous functions? or at that point name spacing is a better option?

Comment: For bigger projects I prefer namespacing. For little once I don't think that multiple self-executing anonymous functions will be a bad thing.

Comment: @delboud: you can have as many anon. funcs as you like. Look at your average jQuery script: `$('#id').on('click',function(){/*anon F*/});` all over the place...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem wasn't sure if I have should have more than one in the global scope but that is a good point when you look at it like that.

Comment: @delboud: in jQ, most of the time your not even in the global scope: `$(document).ready(function(){//your code goes here, in an anon. function`. But really, javascript is a _functional_ language, the more you use them, the better. In fact, using functions well you can write a script without globals _and_ without using `var` even once (closures, and using the arguments, try it and be amazed by the expressiveness)

Answer (score 1):

Read [Principles of Writing Consistent, Idiomatic JavaScript](https://github.com/rwldrn/idiomatic.js/). It's a very good style guide for Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I generally go for something like this. Wrap the whole code in a closure and return one namespace object after attaching all required methods and variables onto that one.

```
var myApp = (function foo() {
    "use strict";
    var myApp = {

        a       : $('.aaa'),
        b       : $('.bbb'),
        c       : $('.ccc'),
        animal  : function () {
            //do stuff
        }
    };

    myApp.pet =  function () {
        //do stuff
    };

    return myApp;
}());


myApp.animal();
```